# kendo ui mvc 4 grid edit selected row

Tags: kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm new to Kendo UI for ASP.NET MVC.
I want to create grid and be able to edit selected row by clicking buttons (create, edit, update, save, cances) that are placed in the toolbar, not in the command collumn. how to achieve this? Here's my code

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<TelerikMVC4.Models.TeacherViewModel>()
  .Name("grid")
  .HtmlAttributes(new{style = "font-size: 12px"})
  .Columns(columns =>
      {
          columns.Bound(teacher => teacher.Name);
          columns.Bound(teacher => teacher.Date).Format("{0:d}");
          columns.Command(commands =>
              {
                  commands.Edit().UpdateText("Save").Text("Edit");
                  commands.Destroy().Text("Delete"); 
              }).Title("").Width(200);
      })
  .ToolBar(toolbar =>
      {
          toolbar.Create().Text("New");
      }) // The "create" command adds new data items
  .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine)
                            .Window(window =>
                                {
                                    window.Title("Edit teacher");
                                }
                            )


  )// Use inline editing mode
  .DataSource(dataSource =>
              dataSource.Ajax()
                  .Model(model =>
                      {
                          model.Id(teacher => teacher.TeacherID); 
                          model.Field(teacher => teacher.TeacherID).Editable(false); 
                      })
                  .Create(create => create.Action("Teachers_Create", "Teacher")) 
                  .Read(read => read.Action("Teachers_Read", "Teacher"))  
                  .Update(update => update.Action("Teachers_Update", "Teacher"))  
                  .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("Teachers_Destroy", "Teacher")) 
  )
  .Pageable(pageable => pageable
                            .Refresh(true)
                            .PageSizes(false)               
                            .ButtonCount(5))
  .Selectable(selectable => selectable.Mode(GridSelectionMode.Single)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if i understood the question.. you want to edit a row with the button Edit outside of the column? if so, it doenst make sense, the edit button must be appended to the row..

Regarding the code i think you are messing with this part of the code:

```
                 .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine)
                        .Window(window =>
                            {
                                window.Title("Edit teacher");
                            }
                        )
```

you are editing inline so why the window title?

```
      @(Html.Kendo().Grid<TelerikMVC4.Models.TeacherViewModel>()
.Name("grid")
 .HtmlAttributes(new{style = "font-size: 12px"})
 .Columns(columns =>
  {
      columns.Bound(teacher => teacher.Name);
      columns.Bound(teacher => teacher.Date).Format("{0:d}");
      columns.Command(commands =>
          {
              commands.Edit().UpdateText("Save").Text("Edit");
              commands.Destroy().Text("Delete"); 
          }).Title("").Width(200);
  })
.ToolBar(toolbar =>
  {
      toolbar.Create().Text("New");
  }) // The "create" command adds new data items
         .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine)
.DataSource(dataSource =>
          dataSource.Ajax()
              .Model(model =>
                  {
                      model.Id(teacher => teacher.TeacherID); 
                      model.Field(teacher => teacher.TeacherID).Editable(false); 
                  })
              .Create(create => create.Action("Teachers_Create", "Teacher")) 
              .Read(read => read.Action("Teachers_Read", "Teacher"))  
              .Update(update => update.Action("Teachers_Update", "Teacher"))  
              .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("Teachers_Destroy", "Teacher")) 
  )
   .Pageable(pageable => pageable
                        .Refresh(true)
                        .PageSizes(false)               
                        .ButtonCount(5))
  .Selectable(selectable => selectable.Mode(GridSelectionMode.Single)))
```